# How to get results from 4 parallel process on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing

I have an executable file `test_run`
and I wan't to run it from console and get output.

For single run, i've used `./test_run | grep '[0-9]*'`
But for 4 parallel runs this solutions doesn't working

```
./test_run | grep '[0-9]*' & ./test_run | grep '[0-9]*' & ./test_run | grep '[0-9]*' &./test_run | grep '[0-9]*'
```

I got from 1 to 4 results time to time. But I need to get stable 4 results each run.

Any ideas how to get output from 4 parallel process? 
BTW I don't have sources.

Comment: Actually Parallel can only come infto picture if you have multiple cores on your server . As in your case you want to trigger 4 instance of your binary at same time , i will suggest you to use 4 identical  crontab entries and divert output to one particular file , hope that meets what you are trying.

Comment: the missing results may be a fake-out from the "terminal" session you're using to run the cmd. To confirm  dropped  items, try wrapping turning above line into a script and then redirecting the scripts output to a file. i.e. `./myWrapperScript.sh > /tmp/wrapperScript.out 2>&1` . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can try GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

you can execute your shell script parallely and grep for the output.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [PDSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdsh/)

It's a very powerful and useful tool

Answer (score 0):

the missing results may be a fake-out from the "terminal" session you're using to run the cmd. To confirm dropped items, try wrapping turning above line into a script and then redirecting the scripts output to a file. i.e. `./myWrapperScript.sh > /tmp/wrapperScript.out 2>&1` . Good luck. – shellter